# SQL query to join multiple tables when no match found

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I need help with writing a sql query. So I have this scenario which requires me to join two tables on a common key and retrieve relevant information using a sql query. In case a match cannot be found, then I would have to join to another table and retrieve a new key to join back to one of these tables. Let me explain it better using some example tables.

```
EMP_TABLE
EMP_ID===NAME===LOCATION
 1      CHRIS   CA
 2      MIKE    FL
 NULL   DAVID   GA
 4      GEORGE  TX

DESC_TABLE
EMP_ID====NAME===JOBDESC
 1       CHRIS   LAWYER
 2       MIKE    DOCTOR
 3       DAVID   ENGINEER
 5       GEORGE  CEO

NEW_EMP_TABLE
NEW_EMP_ID===EMP_ID===NAME
  5             4         GEORGE
```

Here EMP_TABLE is the primary table and we need all the fields from this table plus the JOBDESC field from DESC_TABLE in my result set.

Below is what I would like to capture in my sql query :

1. join EMP_TABLE and DESC_TABLE on EMP_ID and retrieve JOBDESC.
2. If EMP_ID from EMP_TABLE does not match the EMP_ID in DESC_TABLE for any rows, then look up the NEW_EMP_ID value from NEW_EMP_TABLE based on EMP_TABLE.EMPID = NEW_EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID and use that NEW_EMP_ID value to join it back to DESC table on NEW_EMP_TABLE.NEW_EMP_ID = DESC_TABLE.EMP_ID and get the JOBDESC value (look at the row with the name GEORGE for example) .
3. If EMP_ID is null in EMP_TABLE then we should join to DESC_TABLE on EMP_TABLE.NAME = DESC_TABLE.NAME (Row with name DAVID for example).
4. is a pretty straight forward query but when I have to couple that with scenarios 2 & 3, I am not sure how to proceed. I suspect I may have to use nvl and case statements with subqueries.

Any help would be much appreciated. And this query will be executed on Teradata database if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hint: get distinct EMP_ID by union on `EMP_Table` and `NEW_EMP_TABLE`, and select `JOBDESC` from `DESC_TABLE` where `EMP_ID` in your resultant `EMP_ID`s list

Comment: I don't know why you are creating one more table for same kind of data. May be you should re structure your schema

Comment: @Bharadwaj..If there isn't a match on EMP_ID in DESC_TABLE, I would have to go look for the NEW_EMP_ID from NEW_EMP_TABLE based on EMP_ID and use that to join back to DESC_TABLE. If I do a union on EMP_TABLE and NEW_EMP_TABLE and get distinct EMP_ID only, then I would be losing that NEW_EMP_ID row for 5 right? which means I wont be able to match ?

Comment: @zamil, these are just example tables put by me to help explain the scenario better. The actual tables are a bit different but the scenario is still the same.

Comment: As you need only `JOBDESC`, why do you need to join? in your 3rd case, why EMP_ID is null? is it not a PK? In case if you want to join with NAME, then you may not get accurate results as NAME will not be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is rather straightforward in case your scenarios are mutually exclusive. That means the three selects below won't bring multiple records for the same employee. But in that case you need to supply us the logic as to how to deduplicate.

```
select EMP_TABLE.*, DESC_TABLE.JOBDESC
from EMP_TABLE 
join DESC_TABLE 
on EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID= DESC_TABLE.EMP_ID
and EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID is not null

union

select EMP_TABLE.*, DESC_TABLE.JOBDESC
from EMP_TABLE
join NEW_EMP_TABLE
on EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID= NEW_EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID
and EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID is not null 
join DESC_TABLE 
on NEW_EMP_TABLE.NEW_EMP_ID= DESC_TABLE.EMP_ID

union

select EMP_TABLE.*, DESC_TABLE.JOBDESC
from EMP_TABLE 
join DESC_TABLE 
on EMP_TABLE.NAME= DESC_TABLE.NAME
and EMP_TABLE.EMP_ID is null
```

Comment: thank you. I have implemented your suggestion by making a slight modification to the second union statement. I have incorporated the minus operator into the code on EMP_ID between EMP_TABLE and DESC_TABLE, such that only the resulting subset of EMP_ID which are not present in DESC_TABLE would join onto the NEW_EMP table. Appreciate the help.